# Inject a client script or hoot into onbeforeload for a role

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I need to inject javascript before the page is loaded and the other javascript code is executed.

ClientScripts seem to do what I want, but they are not available when creating a Role.
I also cannot find a different way to hook into onbeforeload of a page here.

Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

I checked the ClientScripts mechanism and it seems to work as expected:

```
import { Role } from 'testcafe';

const role = Role('http://example.com', async t => {

    await t.debug();
});

fixture `f`
    .page `http://google.com`;

test('My test', async t => {
    await t.useRole(role);

    await t.debug();
})
    .clientScripts({ content: `console.log('*****: ' + window.location.href );` });
```

Please try this code example and check your browser console during `t.debug()` calls. You can see that the scripts will work as expected.

Comment: I need to execute the clientscript as part of the role

Comment: In the snippet above, the client script will be executed on every page, including during the execution of the role.